# Linux hard drive serial number as non-root

Tags: linux, hardware

First of all, I would like to apologies for the title for not including hardware details. This is because I am looking for a command that will work in all Linux distribution.

Question:

I am very new to Linux and don't know much, however, is it possible to retrieve the hard drive serial number running as non-root. I am aware there are commands available to retrieve this information running using sudo. However, I need a way to retrieve this information without running as sudo.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Mustafa

Answer (score 20):

On most current distributions HDD serial numbers are stored in the udev database, which could be queried without root permissions:

```
/sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name=sda
```

(look for `ID_SERIAL`, `ID_SERIAL_SHORT`; there are also `/dev/disk/by-id/ata-*` symlinks for ATA drives based on those values).

`udisks` provides a higher-level interface to those data and more (it also gives access to SMART attributes without requiring root privileges, which would be needed for calling, e.g., `smartctl` directly).

Comment: You're right, just tried `udisks --show-info` .__But__ it must be noted that when used in batch mode or generally in scripts, `udisks` is WAY slower than `udevadm`.

Answer (score 6):

Another way that usually works is:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/
```

Here's a one liner that gives you a quick enumeration of drive and model/serial number:

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep scsi- | grep -v part | awk '{print $NF " " $(NF-2)}' | sed 's|../../||g' | sed 's/scsi-...._//g'
```

Or for remote machines:

```
ssh $host "ls -l /dev/disk/by-id/ | grep scsi- | grep -v part | awk '{print \$NF \" \" \$(NF-2)}' | sed 's|../../||g' | sed 's/scsi-...._//g'"
```

You can then further process this output. For most drive types, the second string per line is MODEL_SERIAL.

Answer (score 2):

Like womble said, without root access or granting root-like permissions to some process, you can't achieve this. However, since you say you are a newbie, let me note you about a handy command called `lshw`.

Comment: Thank you to both Womble and yourself, very much appreciated. I shall investigate the command you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Short of granting root-like permissions to some process, you can't achieve this.  Even as root you can't do it on some hardware configurations.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Womble. I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0):

The links under /dev/disk/by-id is created by udev. In /etc/udev/rules.d/50-udev.rules such lines can be found:

```
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", SYSFS{ieee1394_id}=="*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$sysfs{ieee1394_id}", ENV{ID_BUS}="ieee1394"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="", IMPORT{program}="/lib/udev/usb_id -x"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="", IMPORT{program}="/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -x -s %p -d $tempnode"
KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="", IMPORT{program}="/lib/udev/scsi_id -g -x -a -s %p -d $tempnode"
KERNEL=="nst[0-9]*|st*|sd*[!0-9]|sr*|dasd*[!0-9]|cciss?c", ENV{ID_SERIAL}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/$env{ID_BUS}-$env{ID_SERIAL}"
```

Unfortunately it is not trivial to find out this `by-id` symlink from the name of the device. But there is at least one direct way:

```
$ udevinfo -q path -n /dev/sda
/block/sda
$ udevinfo -q symlink -p /block/sda
disk/by-id/scsi-SATA_KINGSTON_SVP100_31JY100MY5SK disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:11.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
```

A space separated list is returned. So the `by-id` path can be found.

Or You can directly get the "composite" serial number:

```
$ udevinfo -q env -p /block/sda
ID_VENDOR=ATA
ID_MODEL=KINGSTON_SVP100S
ID_REVISION=CJR1
ID_SERIAL=SATA_KINGSTON_SVP100_31JY100MY5SK
ID_TYPE=disk
ID_BUS=scsi
ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:11.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
```

In the `ID_SERIAL` after the last underscore You can get the serial number.

As I see a serial number can contain alphanumerical characters and '-' (I have such SCSI HDDs). Does anybody know any limitation about the serial number? It if can contain '_' then this method is not bullet proof.

The `ID_MODEL` key could be used to localise more precisely the beginning of the serial number, as (it seems to me) its first 15 characters are added to the `ID_SERIAL` (spaces replaced by '_').

Comment: "udevinfo" did not work for me here on Ubuntu. However, the following one-liner did exactly what I wanted: `udevadm info -q property -xn sda | awk -F\' '/ID_SERIAL_SHORT/{print $2}'` Of course, the `-q property` can be left out, but I always think it's a waste of resources to let `udevadm` output additional lines we don't need at all.